# React is not loaded / Build is not generated

Tags: reactjs, wordpress

I am trying to create a WordPress plugin with React. I am following this [link](https://advent.elliottrichmond.co.uk/loading-react-in-a-wordpress-theme/). I have the following package.json file

```
{
  "name": "test-plugin",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "Sample plugin for React",
  "main": "index.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@wordpress/scripts": "^13.0.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "wp-scripts build",
    "check-engines": "wp-scripts check-engines",
    "check-licenses": "wp-scripts check-licenses",
    "lint:css": "wp-scripts lint-style",
    "lint:js": "wp-scripts lint-js",
    "lint:pkg-json": "wp-scripts lint-pkg-json",
    "start": "wp-scripts start",
    "test:e2e": "wp-scripts test-e2e",
    "test:unit": "wp-scripts test-unit-js"
  },
  "author": "thor",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

I am enqueueing the react script as follows

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'react-script', plugin_dir_url(__DIR__) . 'build/index.js', ['wp-element'], $this->version, false );
```

**ISSUES**

1. The build react js file is not generated. I have followed the above link and everything was installed correctly. But no index.js file is created in build folder
2. The script is not working if I enqueue `src/index.js` instead of `build/index.js`. The script is loaded but not working as expected. I have the div with id `my_app` in one of the pages in which the script is loaded.

Following is the react script file

```
const { render, useState } = wp.element;
 
const Votes = () => {
  const [votes, setVotes] = useState(0);
  const addVote = () => {
    setVotes(votes + 1);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{votes} Votes test</h2>
      <p>
        <button onClick={addVote}>Vote!</button>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};
render(<Votes />, document.getElementById('my_app'));
```

[image: Folder structure]

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem with you and I spent good couple of hours trying to fix this. Here are problem that I encountered:

- One of the issues was the **node_modules folder was in the wrong place**, supposed to be at the same level as your theme.
- The other one was I had to run npm run start instead of npm start. Whenever **wp-scripts** output something like this :

`asset index.js 4.35 KiB [emitted] (name: index)`

`1 related asset asset index.asset.php 107 bytes [emitted] (name: index)`

means it is working. If don't get that means something wrong with your folder location.

Try and let me know.